# Header at the top always and footer at the bottom

Tags: html, css

Basiclly i am try to make my header fix at the top of the page, and at the same time i also need my footer must be at the bottom of the page, whethere there is less or more content. But i don't want my footer position fix. So when ever there is large amout to data footer move with that. The code i am using right now is workin great if i don't make my header fix.

```
<body>
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="content">content</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
</body>
```

CSS for this is

```
    *{ margin:0px; padding:0px;}
    html{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    }
    body {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    }
    #header {
    padding:10px;
    background:#5ee;
    }
#content {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:80px;   /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background:#ee5;
}
```

This is the code, I have not fixed my header in this , but i need some help to it fix.

Comment: replace your role....
#content {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:80px;   /* Height of the footer element */ 
 min-height:700px;
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    position:relative;    
    background:#ee5;
}

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is specifically called "sticky footer".

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: well, that is the name somebody called their implementation of the method =P

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, it seems to me that you're after a sticky header. Try replacing your two rules with following

```
     #header{
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #55EEEE;
        padding: 10px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
     }
     #content{
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF0000;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        height: 2000px;
        margin: 40px 0 0;
        padding: 10px 10px 80px;
     }
```

[Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U5pDm/) changing the `#content` height affects footer position but not header's.

Comment: i can't give the height to my `#content` because the content is very and if there is less `content` then i have to `scroll down` in order to see the footer. So any other option.

Comment: height has been assigned to the _#content_ for demonstration purpose only. Try removing it :)

Answer (score -4):

Use this

```
position:fixed;
```

For your header.

As for footer - use this http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: he explicitly said he doesnt want to use position fixed

Comment: also, what if a content of a page is longer than window area. You would get overlapping effect.